# Передача в функцию rvalue значения

Tags: c++, rvalue

Читал сегодня достаточное количество статей на хабре про rvalue ссылки и семантику перемещения. Вроде бы все понял, но наткнулся на [данный пример](https://habr.com/ru/post/322132/):

```c++
template<class T, class Arg>
T* make_raw_ptr(Arg &&arg)
{
    return new T(arg);
};
```

При передаче rvalue значения, а точнее `make_raw_ptr(A())`, при создании нашего объекта `T` в функции будет вызван конструктор копирования, поскольку arg является lvalue ссылкой. Но почему `arg` не rvalue ссылка, ведь при передаче аргумента в функцию, `Arg = Type`, а значит, `Type&& arg`, вследствие чего, должен быть вызван конструктор перемещения, а не копирования. К сожалению, не могу понять свою ошибку. Помогите разрешить данный вопрос.

Comment: В данном контексте `&&` это не r-value reference а [универсальная ссылка](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)

Comment: Вот поленились сделать для универсальной ссылки отдельный синтаксис, а люди теперь страдают. А ведь могли

Comment: ))) Про универсальные ссылки я понял то как раз, но не понимаю, в какой тип преобразовывается параметр функции при передаче в нее rvalue. lvalue = Type&, rvalue = Type&& при использовании универсальной ссылки, разве не так?)

Comment: потому что в выражение new T(arg) передается как lvalue

Comment: похоже, я понял. arg же это rvalue ссылка, а rvalue ссылка это lvalue значения!!!! правильно?)

Comment: да,  аргументу функции что то присваивается, а потом он используется где то(достаточно повода, чтобы он не был  rvalue.  В любом случаи, я бы посоветовал вам читать  другую статью или учебную литературу . Если вы не поняли, значит  статья плохая.

Comment: я не понял только этот пример. почему то он ввел меня в ступор. на самом деле, я забыл, когда читал, что rvalue ссылка является lvalue, несмотря на то, что он является ссылкой на rvalue. забыл про этот момент и в итоге, с больной головой просидел полдня, даже не пообедав и не поужинав. зато получаешь нереальный кайф, когда разобрал то, над чем ломал голову. за такое я и люблю программирование :)

Answer (score 3):

arg - это rvalue ссылка, а rvalue ссылка это lvalue.
как пример:

```
std::string &&str = std::string("Hello");
std::string *psrt = &str;
```

str — lvalue, хотя его тип rvalue-ссылка.
Это было сказано в указанном в вопросе примере.
Соответственно, в конструктор T передается lvalue, а значит, вызовется конструктор копирования, а не перемещения. Для вызова конструктора перемещения при передаче в функцию rvalue необходимо воспользоваться std::forward или:

```
template<class T>
T&& my_forward(T& a)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(a);
}


template<class T, class Arg>
T* make_raw_ptr(Arg &&arg)
{
    return new T(my_forward<Arg>(arg));
};
```

При передаче rvalue функция my_forward примет следующий вид:

```
template<class T>
Type&& my_forward(Type& a)
{
    return static_cast<Type&&>(a);
}
```

поскольку универсальная ссылка при передаче в неё rvalue параметр T = Type. Следовательно, rvalue ссылка arg передастся по ссылке, как lvalue, и, my_forward вернет rvalue ссылку.
При передаче же lvalue Arg в make_raw_ptr будет эквивалентно Type&.
Тогда my_forward:

```
template<class T>
Type& && my_forward(Type& & a)
{
    return static_cast<Type& &&>(a);
}
```

что равно:

```
template<class T>
Type& my_forward(Type& a)
{
    return static_cast<Type&>(a);
}
```

в итоге чего, нам вернется обычная ссылка.
Если я где-то не прав, подправьте в комментариях, спасибо.

Comment: универсальая,  rvalue  или lvalue есть просто свойства_прилагательное.  Главное что это ссылка, и она может быть левым операндом, а прилагательные придуманы лишь для нужной перегрузки.  Реализация должна решать  вариант  выполнения.